# How to convert a binary! to a char! in Rebol 2?

Tags: binary, char, rebol

It's easy to convert a char to a binary:

```
>> c: #"^(52)"
== #"R"

>> type? c
== char!

>> b: to-binary c
== #{52}
```

But what if I want to go the other way?

```
>> c: to-char b
** Script Error: Invalid argument: #{52}
** Where: to-char
** Near: to char! :value
```

This works in Rebol 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to a string and then extract the first character from the string:

```
>> first to string! #{c3b6}
== #"ö"
```

Note that this decodes the binary as UTF-8 (the default Unicode encoding used in Rebol 3).

Comment: Okay, that works.  But is there a fundamental reason why to-char shouldn't work on a suitable `binary!`?

Comment: The idea is not to invoke default decoding of binaries to strings too often, and rather have the user be explicit that a binary should be decoded. But as long as `to-string` works on `binary!` (and uses an implicit default encoding), I think `to-char` is explicit enough and should accept a `binary!` as well (esp. as `to-char` also accepts a `string!`).

Comment: Dangit, I actually had it backwards.  It's Rebol 2 that can't do this, not Rebol 3!  But your solution is what I was looking for, as I wanted a way to do it that would run in either...

Answer (score 2):

Your original question [asked about Rebol 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14319411/1), where `to-char` *does* work on `binary!`

```
    >> c: #"^(52)"
    == #"R"

    >> type? c
    == char!

    >> b: to-binary c
    == #{52}

    >> c: to-char b
    == #"R"


    >> system/version
    == 2.101.0.3.1
```

However, it does not work in Rebol 2.

Comment: Wait, you are correct...!  It's Rebol **2** where this doesn't work...I had the wrong version!  (I will double check this in the future, haven't made this mistake before.)  Useful to know @earl's solution too, as it works in both Rebol 2 and 3 (which is what I was looking for...)

Comment: I updated your answer with a link to the original question to point out it's me who was confused, not you.  :-)  *Also, if you don't know about it, we have a [Rebol chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) here on StackOverflow...feel free to join!*